# I am looking to update an integer value of one column based on partial data contained in a VARCHAR Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Column A (VAR CHAR) contains a UNC Path eg.

```
lab03-app01\66\2016\10\3\LAB03-REC01\4989\1_6337230127359919046_6337230127366210371.wav
```

Within the UNC Path is an index number 4989.

I need to be able to update Column B (INT) to be equal to the value of Index Number located in Column A.

Is this possible?

Comment: Always the number before the last back-slash?

Comment: You probably want a computed column here. (Will always be consistent, even if the A value is updated.)

Comment: Yes, Always the number before file name.

Answer (score 0):

I think `charindex()` does what you want:

```
select charindex('4989', a)
```

To be safe, you might want to include the delimiters:

```
select charindex('\4989\', a)
```

Comment: You need single quotes in the first example, Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of charindex function.

Comment: That only works if you know the index number ahead of time, which kinda negates the entire need for doing this. So this isn't really a solution at all.

Comment: Very much appreciate the feedback; However pmbAustin is correct as I have 69K+ records requiring an update.

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier with CLR and regular expressions.

One way of doing what you need in TSQL is below ([demo](http://rextester.com/YOPU2978)).

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (A VARCHAR(255), B INT NULL);

INSERT INTO @T(A) VALUES ('lab03-app01\66\2016\10\3\LAB03-REC01\4989\1_6337230127359919046_6337230127366210371.wav')

UPDATE T
SET B = CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(ReverseA, FinalSlash, PenultimateSlash - FinalSlash)) AS INT)
FROM @T T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REVERSE(A))  ca1(ReverseA)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 1 + CHARINDEX('\', ReverseA))  ca2(FinalSlash)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('\', ReverseA, FinalSlash))  ca3(PenultimateSlash);

SELECT *
FROM @T;
```